# How to upgrade ASPNet Identity in .Net Framework web app to work with ASPNet Core 7 Identity?

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-4.8

With .Net 7 Microsoft has released ASP.NET Core Identity 7
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/

I am using two applications in one project

1. .Net Framework 4.7.2 ASPNet MVC web application
2. .Net 7 MVC web application

The # 2 is using newer version of identity and has different mechanism of validating passwords.
Therefore, the same account does not log-into both applications at the same time.

Looking for a solution to either upgrade app #1 with latest version of idendity core but unfortunately core libraries are not supported in .Net Framework.

Any advice please...

I tried installing ASP.NET Core Identity 7 package into .Net Framework 4.7.2 web app but failed.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/